# Zend Rest Controller maps GET to indexAction

Tags: zend-framework, rest

I have a REST setup extending Zend_Rest_Controller. When I call a certain resource, by HTTP GET method it tries to execute `indexAction()` not `getAction()`

When I log the action name using `$this->_request->getActionName()` in the `preDispatch()` it produces `index` while it should map to `get`

Answer (score 0):

[See docs here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.rest):

> Note: If Zend_Rest_Route cannot match a valid module, controller, or
>   action, it will return FALSE and the router will attempt to match
>   using the next route in the router.

So it looks you do not have `getAction()` function in your controller or you working with wrong controller.

Comment: I thought if it is to map HTTP methods, there is no INDEX method

Comment: It behaves differently for post, put, delete you don't have to call them explicitly, if you make a POST request it maps to postAction, same goes for the rest, except the get method which resolves to index which must be called explicitly

Comment: The problem is that I have in the parent controller, and I tried to put it in the child controller just to make sure It's not hallucinating, and it does the same behavior

Comment: It seems there is nothing wrong with the code and the documentation says example.com/api/resource maps to index. Which is against REST conventions. Seems like Zend is making the indexAction mapping to provide a new feature which is not standard with REST

Comment: Seems like zend made a crappy architecture that I have to deal with or extend rest route to handle it. I'd probably choose the first option

Answer (score -1):

This is expected behaviour. GET returns a single instance of an entity, e.g. myhost.com/book/1 would return the book with the ID 1. In contrast, myhost.com/book would return a list of all books available.

Simply try something like:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET http://myhost.com/book/1
```

vs

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET http://myhost.com/book
```

The first call will be delegated to the getAction(), the second to the indexAction()